# Fiddler error 10061

Tags: fiddler

So I don't know how, but I got Fiddler on my computer (I didn't approve any installation), and it's blocking me from using the internet.  Every time I try to access it I get this error:

```
The Socket Connection to the upstream proxy/gateway failed. Closing fiddler, changing your system proxy settings and restarting Fiddler may help. 
ErrorCode 10061. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:14369.
```

I don't know what Fiddler is or where it is installed, because my computer doesn't list it under Tools, Programs, Gadgets, or Chrome Extensions. Where is it installed, and how can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is an internet tracing and debugging tool; if you don't need it, I would uninstall it, but it should do no harm unless it is actively running; but if it is running, all web traffic will be routed through it.

Changes to proxy settings could also indicate a virus, make sure your virus scanner is up to date.

Comment: Fiddler actually changes the browser proxy settings when it's active.

Comment: To follow up on @DrNoone comment, if you just "kill" the process, fiddler will not clean up the proxy settings and you'll be left with a broken internet connection.  Its better to close it normally and then uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to reconfigure your proxy setting settings

Try this:

This was tested in Google chrome and fixed the problem successfully.
Settings -> Show advanced settings -> Under network -> Change Proxy Settings -> Advanced -> Reset

Hope this helps